# fabris.js - know canvas activity

Tags: fabricjs

i am running several JavaScript functions in parallel. some of them download images from and add them to the canvas. other functions draw rectangles on the same canvas.

now, what i dont know is when each function has completed adding their "stuff" to the canvas.

so my question is that is there a way to know if the canvas is "busy" or all operations are done and it's idle.

knowing so will help me code loader windows more efficiently.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a working snippet or fiddle of your code? Some actions that are asynchronous have callbacks that are run when they're complete, while others are synchronous

Comment: I am not sure I can show the code because there are many methods, but mainly adding images or shapes. And they all run at the same time because and there are loops within for adding images and shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing find showing that canvas is busy in adding/updating/moving but i have an idea here

you can use

> canvas.requestRenderAll()

all over instead

> canvas.renderAll();

that will keep queued render request if already there is request in progress.

now there are two events

```
after:render at the end of the render process,event: receives the context in the callback
before:render at start the render process,event: receives the context in the callback
```

ref http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html

using before:render show loader and in after:render with settimeout 100mili sec you can stop loader.

Hope this idea works.

If not please message will try myself

Answer (score 0):

Fabric.js uses callbacks to execute code after performing asynchronous operations. An example would be loading an image which shouldn't be added to a canvas until after the image has loaded.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(imageURL, function(image) {
 //this is the callback that is executed after the image has loaded.
 //include any actions here that you want performed after loading the image
 image.set({ left: 50, top: 50, width:50, height:50 });
 canvas.add(image);
});
```

If you have a list of images you want to load, you can use a recursive function that executes the callback only when the list is complete. Something like this should work:

```js
var images = [src1, src2, src3];
var x = -1;
loopImages(function() {
  //include any actions here that you want performed after loading all images
  alert('All done!');
});

function loopImages(callback) {
  x++; //iterates current index on each loop
  if (x < images.length) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(images[x], function(image) {
      image.set({
        left: 50,
        top: 50,
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      });
      canvas.add(image);
      loopImages(callback);
    });
  } else {
    callback();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using this function. But I have a list of images and so there is a loop. So how would I know that ALL images from the list are loaded into the plasma.

Comment: I've added an additional example for processing a list of images